# Laravel : get data for user using relationships

Tags: laravel, relationship

Get user's answer , question in page by user id , i want to display table for each user contains his answers with questions

I tried to create show page and add show function in UserController

Controller :

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $survey = \App\Survey::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
    $answers = \App\Answer::where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get();

    return view('users.show', compact('user','survey','answers'));
}
```

view:

```php
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>{{ __('Question') }}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Answers') }}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Creation Date') }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($answers as $t)
      <tr> 
        <td> {{ optional($t->survey)->title }} </td>
        <td> {{ $t->answer }} </td>
        <td> {{$t->created_at}} </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer model :

```php
class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['answer','commentaire','user_id','survey_id','last_ip'];
    protected $table = 'answer';

    public function survey()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Survey', 'survey_id');
    }

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

user model :

```php
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}

public function answers() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}
```

the tables :

- answer : [image: Answer's table]
- Survey : [image: Survey table]

I got empty part for question row

Answer (score 0):

You are performing some queries that you actually don't need. 
First get rid of this to lines:

```
 $user_id = $user->id; $survey = \App\Survey::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
```

Then change your query to get your answers:

```
$answers = \App\Answer::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->with(['survey'])->get();
return view('users.show', compact('user','answers'));
```

Now in your view you could just do this:

```
<td> {{ $t->survey->title }} </td>
    <td> {{ $t->answer }} </td>
    <td> {{$t->created_at}} </td>
```

Comment: Thanks and please i want to $t->survey->questions->title but i get error

Comment: you didn't tell anything about Question yet... 
Then do $answers = \App\Answer::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->with(['question'])->get(); and $t->question->title in your view....

Comment: Doesn't work , answer table : id, survey_id , user_id..., survey table: id , question_id ... question : id , survey_id, title ...